# Disable Actions from Chatter Feed in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have embedded the salesforce out of box functionality chatter feed in my visualforce using the below VF tag.

```
<chatter:feed entityId="{!selectedCase.Id}" showPublisher="true" feedItemType="ChangeStatusPost"/>
```

But I want to remove or disable

1, All the actions(Poll, Thanks, File, More) in the chatter and show only discussion. 
2, Remove only poll from chatter and keep all other actions.

Is there any way to achieve the (1) & (2) using visualforce/apex.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fulfill your requirement just add the small code snippet in your code: -

```
<apex:page >

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(".publisherattachtext").hide();//All the actions(Poll, Thanks, File, More) 
            $(".publishericon").hide();//All the actions(Poll, Thanks, File, More) Image
            $("#publishersharebutton").hide();//For share button 
            $(".publisherTextAreaInner").hide();// for text Are where you can type to share
        });
    </script>

    <div id="chatter-container">
        <chatter:feed entityId="{!$User.Id}" />
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

when the page gets loaded Jquery ready function will be called where we are actually hiding all the component mentioned by you.As those feature are salesforce standard feature so we can assume those style class id will remain unchanged.

One more question:

How to remove "internal only" from the below filter.

[image]

Comment: Avijit, your solution worked. Thank you. Appreciated. One more quick question. How to remove "Internal Only" option from 'Show' filter. i have added screen shot for your reference.

Comment: @Menaka if the answer works for u, then accept the answer so that other can find it useful for their requirement.

Comment: @Menaka, also were is your screenshot?

Comment: I have added to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to achieve this upon following these configuration steps:

1. Navigate to Global Actions --> Publisher Layouts and create a new Global Publisher Layout.

In that Layout, remove Poll, Thanks, File and keep whatever actions are necessary.

**Example**

[image: Publisher Action]

2. Assign this page layout to the respective profile using Publisher Layout Assignment.

Now, running your code will show the desired outcome.

```
<chatter:feed entityId="{!selectedCase.Id}" showPublisher="false" feedItemType="ChangeStatusPost"/>
```

**Desired Outcome**

[image: Chatter Layout]